# How to replace first element with different html in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, iframe

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('iframeOnload', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem){
        var spinnerElement = angular.element(' <div id="appApprovalSpinner" class="row text-center approve-spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i></div>');
        elem.replaceWith(spinnerElement);
        angular.element('#appApprovalSpinner').addClass('ng-show');
        elem.on('load', function(){
          angular.element('#appApprovalSpinner').addClass('ng-hide');
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

and here is my html file where to use the directive

```
 <div iframe-onload ></div>
 <iframe id="appApprovedId" ng-if="approvalUrl" class="approve-iframe" ng-class="{'app-approved': isAppApproved}" ng-src="{{trustedApprovalUrl}}" iframe-onload></iframe>
```

I only want to replace the

```
<div iframe-onload ></div>
```

with

```
<div id="appApprovalSpinner" class="row text-center approve-spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i></div>'
```

and keep the iframe as it is because I want onLoad event is called when the iframe is finished loading.
Any suggestion how to replace on the only the div tag but not iframe tag.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please add a pen/plunker. You want to hide the spinner once the iframe is loaded?

Comment: @kim isn't this is what this directive will anyways do? If I didn't understand you correctly do you mind creating a plunker for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing so much DOM manipulation, you can do this easily with `ng-show` and `ng-hide`, and keep track of things with a `$scope` variable that is assigned by the directive.

Change your directive a bit:

```
.directive('iframeOnload', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem){
        scope.ShowSpinner = true;
        var spinnerElement = angular.element('<div ng-show="ShowSpinner" class="row text-center approve-spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i></div>');
        elem.append(spinnerElement);
        elem.on('load', function(){
          scope.ShowSpinner = false;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I have done this way too but I think that if someone wants to use directive she/he has to create the div tag and update the controller as well.

Comment: So it sounds like you're looking for a directive that does 100% (kind of like a plugin).

Comment: I updated the code a bit to reflect this.  Now the scope variable is set internally by the directive so it never needs to be set in the controller.  Try this approach and see how it works.

Comment: Dr. Cool. Have you upload your updated code to reflect this? How to have the div in the directive instead of html file. If someone wants to use this directive then she/he has to create the <div tag with the spinner

Comment: Check it now. I used your code to create the ``<div>`` element in the directive.

Comment: Dr. Cool. How about html file? Do we need to have extra <div . I have tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes
Directive:

```
 .directive('iframeOnload', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        isRequired: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem){
        var spinnerElement = angular.element(' <div ng-if="isApprovalRequired" id="appApprovalSpinner" class="row text-center approve-spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i></div>');
        if ( (angular.element(elem).hasClass('spinner')) && scope.isRequired ) {
          elem.replaceWith(spinnerElement);
        }
        angular.element('#appApprovalSpinner').addClass('ng-show');
        elem.on('load', function(){
          angular.element('#appApprovalSpinner').addClass('ng-hide');
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

and in the html file I have this

```
 <div class="spinner" iframe-onload  is-required="isApprovalRequired"></div>
 <iframe id="appApprovedId" ng-if="approvalUrl" class="approve-iframe" ng-class="{'app-approved': isAppApproved}" ng-src="{{trustedApprovalUrl}}" iframe-onload></iframe>
```

It worked but still need the  in there. Note It won't work if there is no  tag there 
Any solution to make it works without the extra  tag ?